# user actions and different app states in ios apps

Tags: ios

I'm new to ios dev.I want to know what will be the state of my app in different ios versions after following user actions?

1. **User presses home key.**
2. **User locks screen.**

In my app's case(developed in swift) app's state remains preserved.

I too have a doubt about 2 possible states:-

**1. Background state - as per apple's doc most apps enter background
    state *briefly* on their way to being suspended.**

**2. Suspension state - as per apple's doc no computing takes place in
    this state .**

I have seen many apps doing some work after pressing home button e.g browser loading page etc.

How this can happen??

I searched a lot over web for this but all Q&A are obsolete.

Comment: The best reference is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html.  The amount of background time available has changed with different iOS versions.

Comment: @Phillip Thanks....................